# Can't call ajax method with param using in ui:repeat using f:ajax

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, facelets

I have a list of links rendered in a loop. On click of the link I want to set a bean property `selectedIndex`. I am trying to do it by passing it on Ajax parameter, but the full form is getting refreshed. Even then the `notificationPreferencesBean.retrievePreferences` is not getting fired. Is this approach correct?

Here is my template snippet:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{notificationPreferencesBean.userNotificationPreferences}"
   var="userNotificationPreferenceVar" varStatus="idx">
    <li>
        <h:commandLink
           value="#{userNotificationPreferenceVar.notificationClassName.label}"
           styleClass="#{userNotificationPreferenceVar.cssClassName}"
           action="#{notificationPreferencesBean.retrievePreferences}">
           <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none">
                <f:param value="#{idx}" name="idx" />
           </f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink>
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

and here is the bean declaration:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.idx}")
private Integer selectedIndex;
```

Interestingly the following code works Ajaxfully but it just calls the `notificationPreferencesBean.retrievePreferences` and doesn't set the selectedIndex(as expected because I am not passing any param)

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{notificationPreferencesBean.userNotificationPreferences}"
   var="userNotificationPreferenceVar" varStatus="idx">
    <li>
        <h:commandLink
          value="#{userNotificationPreferenceVar.notificationClassName.label}"
          styleClass="#{userNotificationPreferenceVar.cssClassName}"
          action="#{notificationPreferencesBean.retrievePreferences}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

Is there any other way of doing it?
I just want to set selectedIndex property on click of the link ajaxfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the annotation `@ManagedProperty` for that.

Just use a [`f:setPropertyActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{notificationPreferencesBean.userNotificationPreferences}"
   var="userNotificationPreferenceVar" varStatus="idx">
    <li>
        <h:commandLink
           value="#{userNotificationPreferenceVar.notificationClassName.label}"
           styleClass="#{userNotificationPreferenceVar.cssClassName}"
           action="#{notificationPreferencesBean.retrievePreferences}">
           <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{idx}"
               target="#{notificationPreferencesBean.selectedIndex}" />
           <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
```